# How to open a new Tab with bind parameters using java script

Tags: javascript

This is my function. I want to open a new window with the below URL and pass these parameters.

```
 function viewWeightAge() {
            var userNIC = document.getElementById("NICNo");
            var childName = document.getElementById("childName");
            window.location.href = "https://localhost:8080/KiddieCare/AdminPanel/WeightAgeGraph.jsp?childName="+childName+"&userNIC="+userNIC;
         
        }
```

can anyone explain me the error?

Question Updated.

```
function showWeightAge(){
    var userNIC = document.getElementById("NICNo");
            var childName = document.getElementById("childName");
            var parameters= userNIC,childName;
            window.open ('https://localhost:8080/KiddieCare/AdminPanel/WeightAgeGraph.jsp','Window Name',parameters);
}
```

I Have tried. It's an open new Window.  Like this[image]

using window.open() I can open a window but I want to send parameters to the new JSP.

Comment: this seems to change the url of currently open window/tab so this code will move user on a window where you will run it to provided url, not open new window with provided url. Is this intended? If not than you should use this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: are you sure that you can use`https` with `localhost:8080`? Try `window.open('http://localhost:8080/...");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `window.location.href` which change the url of the current window

you should use `window.open()`
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Note that it could be blocked as an unwanted popup

In your case it can be done as

```js
function viewWeightAge() {
     const userNIC = document.getElementById("NICNo");
     const childName = document.getElementById("childName");
     window.open("https://localhost:8080/KiddieCare/AdminPanel/WeightAgeGraph.jsp?childName="+childName+"&userNIC="+userNIC);
}
```

Comment: Yeah the "right" way to do this (assuming it originates from a user's action) is to create a link and .click it since `window.open` is almost always blocked

Comment: using window.open() I can open a window but I want to send parameters to the new JSP

Comment: Why don't you do `window.open("https://localhost:8080/KiddieCare/AdminPanel/WeightAgeGraph.jsp?childName="+childName+"&userNIC="+userNIC")` as you had done for the `window.location`

Comment: @CharybdeBE I got an Error saying window.location is not a function

Comment: @PoornaSenaniGamage Yes because the function i told you to  use is window.open (i will edit my answer to be clearer)